# How do I have concurrent read and write locks in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, concurrency

Here is a snippet from `db.currentOp()`:

```
{
        "opid" : 71144,
        "active" : false,
        "op" : "query",
        "client" : "127.0.0.1:41889",
        "desc" : "conn2",
        "threadId" : "0x7fc3e4b4d700",
        "connectionId" : 2,
        "locks" : {
                "^pophealth-production" : "W"
        },
        "waitingForLock" : true,
        "numYields" : 0,

},
{
        "opid" : 70981,
        "active" : true,
        "secs_running" : 2647,
        "op" : "query",
        "ns" : "pophealth-production.records",
        "query" : {
                "$msg" : "query not recording (too large)"
        },
        "client" : "127.0.0.1:41890",
        "desc" : "conn3",
        "threadId" : "0x7fc3e4a4c700",
        "connectionId" : 3,
        "locks" : {
                "^" : "r",
                "^pophealth-production" : "R"
        },
        "waitingForLock" : false,
        "numYields" : 5,
```

How is it possible that one thread holds a write lock but another thread holds a read lock? Shouldn't a write lock prevent a read lock? Or does the `active: false` flag mean that the lock isn't actually being held by the first process?

Comment: No, MongoDB currently has a single threaded write greedy write/read lock as can be seen by the "waitingForLock"

Comment: So the first thread doesn't actually have the write lock? I don't understand how greediness affects this

Comment: I forgot to mention that the write lock is on database level currently which means that concurrent writes can occur over databases, soon documents. however, you cannot read and write to the same space else you will get inconsistencies. No, the first thread is waiting for the second to yield in this case. Greediness will become involved in greater load, currently it does not effect your knowledge, I merely added it since it is correct to say that

Comment: The only way to get concurrent reads and writes without (techincally) inconsistentcies is to use MVCC but that involves a lot more problems

Comment: That of course being said that techs like SQL have the ability to read one table while write another, however, I believe MongoDB does not yet have such ability

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. When you say "the first thread is waiting for the second to yield" does that mean that the first thread doesn't actually have a lock?

Comment: Indeed it does not, it is waiting for lock, as shown by `"waitingForLock" : true,`